# What will be the probability that a line will pass through the inscribed rectangle?

Tags: probability

Just out of curiosity, I was playing with this problem. 
There is a small rectangle inside a bigger rectangle. The location of the smaller rectangle can be anywhere inside the bigger but it will always be inscribed. Let's say I draw a line that pass through the bigger rectangle than what is the probability that this line also pass through the smaller rectangle?

Comment: I assume the dimensions of the smaller and bigger rectangle are given. Are the sides of these rectangles parallel to each other? Is the location of the smaller rectangle within the bigger rectangle given or random? If random, presumably uniformly distributed over all possible positions? Now the difficult part: You need to specify a distribution for the lines. Are all orientations equiprobable? And given an orientation, are all positions of the line in which it intersects the bigger rectangle equiprobable?

Comment: Thanks to joriki! I think this problem should be formulated more carefully. The dimension of both the rectangles are known and sides are parallel. However I think orientation should not affect the solution. The location of the center of smaller rectangle is uniformly distributed over the bigger rectangle. all lines (orientation and position) are equiprobable. Thanks

Comment: "all lines (orientation and position) are equiprobable" is somewhat unclear. You could make the orientations equiprobable, and then for each orientation make the positions in which the line intersects the big rectangle equiprobable. Or you could make the distribution uniform with respect to all combinations of orientations and positions for which the line intersects the big rectangle; but then the orientations with a larger range of intersecting positions would be more probable. You can only have one or the other.

Comment: Also, if the centre of the smaller rectangle is uniformly distributed over the bigger rectangle, then the smaller rectangle will sometimes extend beyond the bigger rectangle. I'd taken your "inscribed" formulation to mean that it's always fully inside the bigger rectangle. In any case, you should explicate what you mean by "inscribed", since this is not standard terminology applied to this case.